# more less example with coffeescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, toggle

I'm trying to add basic more/less links to toggle element visibility.

How do I insert `preventDefault` ?

Also it only works on first toggle, after that it doesn't toggle out. Any error?

```
$("#description-link").click ->
  $("#project-description").show()
  $(this).text("Show description")
, ->
  $("#project-description").hide()
  $(this).text("Hide description")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could try something like this instead:

```
$("#description-link").click (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  $('#project-description').toggle()
  a = $(this).text()
  a = if (a == 'Show Details') then 'Hide Details' else 'Show Details'
  $(this).text(a)
```

And apparently the space between `click` and `(e)` is required. Otherwise a TypeError is thrown.

*EDIT:* Just realized why the space is required...as it's part of the function declaration. Haven't really messed with Coffeescript before. /facepalm

Answer (score 1):

To access preventDefault(), you need to add the event argument to your function, and call the preventDefault method on that:

```
$("#description-link").click (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  ....
```